# on scroll of child div scroll parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want a `#nav` to be on top but above the `#nav` there is some text.on scroll of the `#child` div i should be able to scroll main scroll bar of the body then the `#nav` should be fixed on top!and there should be scrolling for only `#child` div.

heres the reference..
http://jsfiddle.net/maUYK/

```
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
        <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
  <div id="child">
  <table>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
         <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit. It doesn't clear as to what you want? Do you want only the contents of the table to scroll keeping the border lines as they are?

Comment: In simple words He wants a fixed #nav

Comment: i want to scroll the content of the table at the same time i want to scroll the body too!! simultaneous scrolling of body and table!!

Comment: @TabraizAli What you are looking for is a fixed navigation and scrolling body , isnt it ?

Comment: @harsh8888 simultaneous scrolling of #child and body scroll bar till #nav !! then #nav should be fixed..then i should be able to scroll only #child div!

Comment: @Shail fixed navigation with scrolling body is  correct!! on scroll of the #child div that should be done !!not on scroll of parent div!!

Comment: @TabraizAli  What you need to do is  set the ids on the #child div for the navigation ie for #nav . And you will have to use scroll spy javascript to detect the ids assigned to the nav element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nav{
    position:absolute;
       top:200px;
     left:0;
     }

     #nav.fixed{
     position:fixed;
         top:10px;
        }
```

Use the above styles to position navigation and fix after the scroll

For info you can visit this link - `http://addyosmani.com/blog/rocketbar/`

Answer (score -1):

The height of the div is too large. Give the height 200px, that's all right.

```
 div {
     overflow: scroll;
     height: 200px;
     width: 520px;
 }
```